# Latest build of iOS app not running on device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have built an iOS application, and have run it many times on different devices. However, this time I am running it on an iPhone 5, and it always builds an old version of the application. The app was submitted and rejected by apple. I made a bunch of changes to the app in Xcode, which are apparent when I run the app in the simulator, but not when I run it on my iPhone 5. What should I do to get the latest version of my app to run on the iPhone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured out my problem. I had an idea that there was something wrong in the build settings. So, I created a new game from the game template in Xcode, then made sure that all of the non-app-specific build settings were the same in my game as they were in the newly created game. Doing this solved the problem!

Comment: You figured out your problem but you have chosen the other answer? Your meant to choice the answer that best help solve your problem which is clearly your answer that you have given. Removed pointless thanks as that is a comment not part of an answer.

Answer (score 0):

First off, welcome to Stack Overflow!

Second, a few quick possible solutions: try deleting the app on your device, restarting Xcode, and going to "Product > Clean" in Xcode, before re-building the new version.

Alternatively, check the top-left of your Xcode window, next to the Build and Stop buttons, and make sure your active scheme settings are correct (i.e. that you're building the right version of the app and that you're sending it to your iOS device).

If neither of those options work, add a bit more detail to your question and I'll update my answer with more suggestions.  Have you ever built this app on this device using Xcode?  When was the last time?  What changed between then and now?